# why some device driver have multiple version?

Tags: windows-7, drivers

when we want install device driver there are diferent device driver for each version of windows.
e.g:debice driver for windows xp x86 is different from windows 7 x86 and windowd 8 x86
Why need Different device driver for each version of windows?
why cant have same driver for all version or only have 2 for x86 and x64??
i want explain it in more technical detail

Comment: Some drivers *are* multi-version. Typically newer kernels in later versions allow better interaction between the OS and driver through new functionality, so drivers then have to be developed to use those, and others maintained to be backwards compatible. [Read this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff554887(v=vs.85).aspx) for a little more information

Comment: @BenN  tnx for link but i neef technical detail

Comment: This is starting to sound like a homework question.

Comment: @CharlieRB no!i do some research in device driver

Comment: different Windows versions have differnet features/APIs. See here for NDIS: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn449742(v=vs.85).aspx, https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/hh463937(v=vs.85).aspx) for example. This shows new API and so you need different drivers for different Windows versions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because different versions of Windows don't work in the same way, many drivers have to be updated because many libraries that the drivers use are not in the same place or have the same structure or way (code, method, language) to manipulate the system, or the drivers use different libraries as dependencies, and maybe a lot of more reasons (your device has a different UI or more options that can't be used in another version).

Comment: can u explian more in detail? ?

Comment: If you cannot understand the answer then I fear your computer knowledge is lacking some basic fundamentals. What is it exactly that you don't understand?

Comment: @DavidPostill  i understand it but it is simple answer. i want advanced explanation

Answer (score 0):

Every OS has its own compatibility issues. 
Suppose you are using windows XP and you have downloaded its drivers, then you upgraded your OS to windows 7 or 8, The drivers for windows XP wouldn't be enough for windows 7 because, the latest version of windows comes with new features and new framework etc. When you do the vice-versa, the drive wouldn't install in XP because of the compatibility issues.

In the case of versions 32-bit(x86) and 64-bit(x64), the 32-bit drivers work efficiently on  32-bit OS  but those drivers wouldn't be enough for the 64-bit OS, because of the extra features in the 64-bit OS. For more effective work of PC, it is better  to use 64-bit drivers in 64-bit OS.